# Date and Time picker in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, calendar, timepicker

**I know this question is on SO a few times already but I cannot find a working or suitable answer.**

I want a date picker which includes a time picker.  I don't want any fancy frills etc, just something that works.  Preferably one control I can drag into the tool box in `VS`, register at the top and work with.  I have been playing around with many versions the last few days and I can't get one to work.  They normally seem to include too many files for me or something stupid.  A project I am working on now hinges on this stupid thing so any advice would be welcome.  I have previously managed to get a calendar control and put some validation on a text-box to pick times.  However I cannot take both of these values and enter them into my database as on Date-time field because when I try to use "Selected-date" to get the time it naturally says that text-boxes cannot be members of the "Selected-date" property.

As I have a calendar control in to pick the date and a validated textbox to type in the time I tried to use the following code.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim time As String() = txtTime.SelectedDate.ToString().Trim().Split(" "C)
    Dim [date] As String() = cldDate.SelectedDate.ToString().Trim().Split(" "C)
    Dim datetime__1 As String = [date](0) & " " & time(1) & time(2)
    Dim DateTimeValue As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(datetime__1)
    Response.Write(DateTimeValue.ToString())
    ' Update database with DateTimeValue.  
End Sub
```

The code `txtTime.SelectedDate.ToString()` is a problem here.  It says that `SelectedDate` is not a supported member of textbox.  This is code that I have came across.  I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: What's wrong with entering a time from a textbox? You could use some javascript to insert the `:` after the first two numbers are typed, and then validate using regex.

Comment: @JackPettinger Please see the edited question.  It should give you a better idea of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new instance of the DateTime structure. The DateTimePicker.SelectedValue returns a Nullable(Of DateTime), so you can use the values of this to create a new DateTime (along with the values from your textboxes).

For example:

```
Dim myDateTime As New DateTime(cldDate.SelectedDate.Year, cldDate.SelectedDate.Month, cldDate.SelectedDate.Day, HourValue, MinuteValue, 0)
```

Just replace `HourValue` and `MinuteValue` with your values from your textboxes. Note you should convert these to Integers.

Note the 0 at the end represents seconds.

This should save to the database fine.

For more info on DateTime see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: i'm working on this suggestion at the moment.  I had my time text box as one so i am trying to put in two dropdownlists now so that the user can pick the hour and minute.  I have to parse the strings over to ints though.  Hopefully should be able to test this soon and get back to you.  Thanks

Comment: That worked.  Once I figured out how to parse it etc it has worked.  Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if jQuery is an option i would [look at this plug in](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

clean and easy to implement

Comment: Thanks.  I have created the pages it mentions.  I am a bit confused as to how to actually call this an implement it on my page now.  Any advice?

Comment: 1. add a text box to your page for date time
2. give it a jquery-able name (id/class/data tag)
3. add the lib to your code and include on the page
4. call method to set up text box as a date time picker

if you need a complete example i will be happy to provide but i prefer to nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether a commercial product would be an option for you.

We are using [telerik](http://www.telerik.com)'s RadDateTimePicker in our projects (and there are certainly other commercial products). [See this page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datetimepicker/accessibility/defaultcs.aspx) for a demo of the datetime picker control.

Comment: I had looked into this and it does seem like a great control but unfortunately paying for the controls is not an option. I dont mean to sound like a cheap skate but i am working on a uni project here so its not suitable to buy controls.  Thanks though